# Using proof by contraposition to show that if $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $3n+2$ is even, then $n$ is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have my answer below but there is one step that I am not understanding...and maybe my brain is just not trained to understand it.

> Prove that if $n$ is an integer and $3n+2$ is even, then $n$ is even using a proof by contraposition.
>
> The contraposition would read: if $n$ is an integer and $3n+2$ is odd, then $n$ is odd.
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> n
> &= 2k+1 \\
> &= 3\left(2k+1\right) + 2 \\
> &= 6k+5 \\
> &= 2\left(3k+2\right) + 1 \text{(this is the step I don't understand)}
> \end{align*}
> $$

Ok, so I understand everything up until the last step. I understand how I got to $6k + 5$, but what I don't understand is how I can prove that last statement? I know that $2\left(2k + 2\right) + 1$ means that the number is odd and the contraposition has now be proofed. And I understand that we got to $2\left(3k+2\right)+1$, then dividing by $2$, but $5/2$ isn’t $2$.

Comment: The contrapositive is "If n is odd, then 3n+2 is odd."

Comment: am i not saying the same thing by `if n is an integer and 3n+2 is odd, then n is odd`. Not trying to be snarky, just still learning like crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the contrapositive of '*$A$ implies $B$*' is '*not $B$ implies not $A$*'.

In this case, now -staying withing the realm of integers- it would read

> If $n$ is odd, then $3n+2$ is odd.

And this is being proved. The equality sign on the second line is not correct, as $n=2k+1\ne 3n+2$, so it should be

> Suppose $n$ is odd, i.e. $n=2k+1$. 
>   Then $3n+2=2(3k+2)+1$, i.e. can be written of the form $2x+1$ with $x\in\Bbb Z$, so it is odd.

Well, it would be also enough to note that $3n+2=6k+5$ and $6k$ is even, $5$ is odd, their sum is odd.

Even simpler: If $n$ is odd, then $3n$ is odd, so $3n+2$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that$$6k + 5 = 6k + 4 + 1 = 2(3k + 2) + 1$$

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense...but how would i know to do 6k+4+1? Should I just do what makes sense to arrive at n=2k +1?

Comment: Well $5 = 4 + 1$. Then $6k + 5 = 6k + (4 + 1) = (6k + 4) + 1 = ...$ Just using simple algebra and associativity.

Comment: thank you. i took algebra a while back so this is kicking my butt now. much appreciated.

Comment: You're very welcome. Don't worry, you get it back in no time.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive of $P \to Q$ is $\lnot Q \to \lnot P$ so in your case the contrapositive would be : If $n$ is odd, then $3n+2$ is odd. (It seems you have this reversed in your statement of the contrapositive.)

That's why the start of the proof of the contrapositive is $n=2k+1$ (i.e. $n$ is odd), and then the computation of $3n+2=3(2k+1)+2=6k+5=6k+4+1=2(3k+2)+1$ shows the desired thing, that $3n+2$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to use the language of congruences: being odd means being congruent to 1 modulo $2$, being even is being congruent to $0$.

Anyway, since $3$ is odd, $3n+2\equiv n \mod 2$, so the result is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Q5) Prove that   " if $n$ is an  integer and $3n + 2$ is odd,  then  $n$ is odd "
(Hint  using  proof by contraposition ; i.e. $\neg q\to\neg p\equiv p\to q$ )

Comment: Consider formatting your posts here with MathJax. It helps others to interpret your answers properly.